# PyQGIS: iface.addVectorLayer problem in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyqgis, ubuntu, linux

I am running a simple PyQGIS script (QGIS 2.18.17) in Ubuntu to read a shapefile.
First I tried QgsVectorLayer function and it worked well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from qgis.core import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

uri = "/home/aka000/site4/PyQGIS/output_test.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, '' , 'ogr' )

if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Then, I tried to read it using iface.addVectorLayer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()


uri = "/home/aka000/site4/PyQGIS/output_test.shp"

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(uri, '', 'ogr')

if not layer:
    print "Layer failed to load!"
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addVectorLayer'
```

I create a .py file in Linux and run it from the Command Line (Terminal):
[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164950/2856

Comment: @user2856 I looked at this post, but I could not find a clear solution. Can you please explain more about how to fix it if you know it?

Comment: The "fix" is to use `QgsVectorLayer` per your 1st example, you can't use `iface` outside of QGIS.